# Tangent space on a regular submanifold

Tags: differential-geometry, smooth-manifolds

Let $f:M\rightarrow N$ be a submersion between two smooth manifolds, and let $P=f^{-1}(q)$ where $q\in N$.

I want to show that $T_pP=\ker f_{*p}$  $\forall p\in P$. I need some tips on where to start because I am really lost here.

Comment: Start from the definition of the tangent space to $M$ at $p$ and the definition of the linear map $f_{*p}$.